# Let $\mathcal{f}$ be a one-to-one function from $A$ into $B$ with $B$ finite. Show that $A$ is finite.

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

My question is let $\mathcal{f}$ be a one-to-one function from $A$ into $B$ with $B$ finite. Show that $A$ is finite.

This is my attempt:

Since $\mathcal{f}$ is one-to-one, $A$~$\mathcal{f}(A) \subset B$. Since $B$ is finite and $A \subset B$, then $A$ is finite.

(Here the ~ is an equivalence relation.)

Is this correct or am i doing something wrong?

I know there are propostions that state:

1.) If A is finite and there exists an onto function $\mathcal{f}:A \twoheadrightarrow B$ the B is finite.

2.) If $A$ is infinite and there exists a one-to-one function $\mathcal{f}:A \hookrightarrow B$, then $B$ is infinite.

Answer (score 0):

Your proof is correct, provided you can use that subsets of a finite set are finite.

If you can't, you should use the proposition 1. Since $f$ is one to one, $f^{-1}$ is a function and it is an onto function $f^{-1}:f(B) \twoheadrightarrow A$.

Comment: $f^{-1}$ is not defined on all of $B$.

Comment: @QingZhang My definition of one-to-one functions says that $f$ is one-to-one if it's injective and surjective.

Comment: isnt the definition of one-to-one function injective only

Comment: Any case, I wrote $f(B)$ instead of $B$. This should work with both definitions.

Comment: Probably you mean $f(A)$ instead of $f(B)$.